# How to check if TPU device type is v2 or v3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, tpu

Is there any python API in tensorflow (or any other way) to check if the TPU accelerator is v2 or v3 TPU?

Comment: Not sure if there is an API in python, but you can see the TPU version from the google cloud console by this command `gcloud compute tpus list`. See, if it helps. https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to know TPU device type using `tf.profiler.experimental.client.monitor`. To use TPU in colab, you need to create TPU strategy in the first step.

Please refer completed code as shown below

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
import os

try:
  tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
  print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])
except ValueError:
  raise BaseException('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the previous cell in this notebook for instructions!')

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
```

Output:

```
Running on TPU  ['10.96.157.82:8470']
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.96.157.82:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Initializing the TPU system: grpc://10.96.157.82:8470
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Clearing out eager caches
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished initializing TPU system.
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 0, 0)
```

TPU system initialized at `10.96.157.82:8470`, but profiler service has been started in all the TPU workers at `8466` port, hence you have to replace `8470` with `8466`

```
tpu_worker = os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'].replace('8470', '8466') 
print(tf.profiler.experimental.client.monitor(tpu_worker,1))
```

Output:

```
  Timestamp: 15:37:16
  TPU type: TPU v2
  Utilization of TPU Matrix Units (higher is better): 0.000%
```

From this output you can get to know type of TPU. For more information please refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/python/profiler/profiler_client.py).